# numba and numpy.expand_dims

Tags: python, numba

I'm rewriting some of my functions to be suitable for Numba. Now I have a function that I call multiple times within my script with input arrays of different dimensions.

```
def FormHistMatrix2(x,Whc,Lm):
    if x.ndim == 1:
       x = np.expand_dims(x,axis=1)
    [N,Ncells] = x.shape
```

This is the beginning of my function, and Numba is throwing the following error:

```
TypingError: Cannot unify array(float64, 2d, A) and array(float64, 3d, A) for 'x', defined at C:/Users/DNP_Student_3/Documents/Python Scripts/GCFuncsTests.py (332)
```

In this case 'x' is a 2D-array but in other cases it can be a 1-D array.
So doesn't Numba like the if loop? Or what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Numba, unlike standard python, a variable cannot change its type during the execution of a function. You should be able to assign the result of the call to `np.expand_dims` to another variable and it will work. It is ok if sometimes `x` is 1d and sometimes it's 2d as long as there is consistency in the types of all of the variables across the execution of the function.

Comment: Yes, I know thet numba doesn't like changing variable types but I expected that it would skip the if loop when `x` would be 2-D but apparently it doesn't. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What JoshAdel said is true in general, but the problem in this case is that you need a different implementation/specialization of your function depending on the input type.

Numba has the [`@generated_jit`-decorator](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/generated-jit.html) for this case.

In your case you'd need to write a specialized expand-dims function which is depending on the dimensions of the input array:

```
import numba as nb
@nb.generated_jit(nopython=True)
def nb_expander(x):
    if x.ndim == 1:
        return lambda x: np.expand_dims(x, axis=1)
    else:
        return lambda x: x
```

This function needs to be called from within your other function:

```
@nb.njit
def FormHistMatrix2(x, Whc, Lm):
    x = nb_expander(x)
    [N, Ncells] = x.shape
```

This will now work for `x` of dimensions 1 and 2. For `x.ndim==3` you also need to implement a similar method for the shape.